# sh4gcc cross-compiler installation for Centos 7

Tags: centos, rpm, gcc, cross-compilation

I am trying to compile a program which requires sh4gcc cross-compiler and I'm not able to find any rpm package which provides sh4gcc compiler.

On executing this command

```
[root@localhost stapp]# make all
```

I get the following output

```
make: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[1]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[1]: sh4gdb: Command not found
Building STDVM...
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm'
make[2]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[2]: `/b2067/h205/b2067_h205.mak' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[2]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
---- Building libstdvm.a ----
make -C /opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src'
make[4]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[4]: `/b2067/h205/b2067_h205.mak' is up to date.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[4]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
---- Building libstdvm.a ----
make[5]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm'
make[6]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[6]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[6]: `/b2067/h205/b2067_h205.mak' is up to date.
make[6]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[6]: sh4gdb: Command not found
make[6]: Entering directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
---- Building libstprm.a ----
Compiling /opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/stprm_dvr.c
sh4gcc  -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/platform/b2067_h205 -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/platform/Default -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/include/internal -DMOSAIC_SUPPORT -DMOSAIC_SUPPORT  -DUSE_STFRONTEND -DSTPTI_TPLOADER -DSTPTI_NO_STTKD -DSTPTI_DVB_SUPPORT -DST_H205 -DST_h207 -DSDK_MEMORY_CONFIG=256 -DSTFDMA_USE_VIRTUAL_CONTEXT -DVIDEO_USE_VIRTUAL_FDMA_MODE -DDVD_STTBX_RELAY -DSTVTG_CLK_HDMI -DSTVTG_HDMI -DHDMI_CEC_ON -DSTHDMI_CEC -DSERVICE_DVB -DSTVID_DEBUG_GET_STATISTICS -DSTVID_DEBUG_GET_DISPLAY_PARAMS -DSTAUD_DEBUG_STATISTICS -DSTAPI_INTERRUPT_BY_NUMBER -DATAPI_USING_INTERRUPTS -DSTSUBT_COMMON_INPUT_SUPPORT -DRDE_DISPLAY_SERVICE -DDISABLE_OSD_DISPLAY_SERVICE -DRDE_ENABLE_NOTIFY_COMMAND_IS_POSTED -DSTTTX_SUBT_SYNC_ENABLE -DSTTTX_SYNC_OFFSET=0 -DSTFDMA_TTS_SUPPORT -DSTI2C_NO_PIO -DSTPOWER_NO_DEVICE_CHECK -DSTPOWER_SUPPORTED -DDVD_STCLOCK -DSTVOUT_ENHANCED_HDMI -DSERVICE_DVB -DUSB -DOSPLUS -DSTDVM_METADATA_SUPPORT -DSTDVM_ENABLE_CRYPT -DSTDVM_PATCH_IPRG -DDVR -DSDK_VERSION=99 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  -DDISPLAY_SD=D_PAL -DDISPLAY_HD=D_1080I50HZ -DSTCLKRV_EXT_CLKA_MHZ=30 -DSTCLKRV_EXT_CLKB_MHZ=0 -DSTCLKRV_EXT_CLK_MHZ=0 -DRUN_FROM_FLASH -DDVD_ADDRESSMODE=32 -DHARDWARE_REVISION=1  -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/board/h205/bsp-st40-5.1.0/inc -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/include -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/include -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/include/traces -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/include/internal -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/chip -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/platform/b2067_h205 -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/platform/Default -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/platform/b2067/h205 -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/platform/b2067/h205/bootrom -I/include -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/src/multicom/v4.0.6P3/os21/source/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -Wall  -DDVD_JITTER_PROFILE_IP_MS=0 -DDVD_ADDRESSMODE=32 -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -DOS21_RUNTIME -DST40_OS21 -mruntime=os21 -Db2067 -DST_H205 -DARCHITECTURE_ST40 -DST_OS21 -DST_h207 -DOSPLUS -DSTPRM_RAP_INDEX_SUPPORT -DSTPRM_DVR_SUPPORT -DSTPRM_STARTUP_VSYNC -DSTPRM_PTI_RECORD_BUFFER_SUPPORT  -DDVD_TRANSPORT_STPTI5 -DDVD_TRANSPORT_STPTI -DSTPRM_PATCH_IPRG -DSTPRM_PTI_RECORD_BUFFER_SUPPORT  -DDVD_TRANSPORT_STPTI5 -DDVD_TRANSPORT_STPTI    -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/.. -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/include -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/src/stos -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/src/stcommon -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/src/stinject -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/src/stbuffer -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/chip/.. -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/chip -I/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/apilib/config/board -I/b2067/h205  -o stprm_dvr.o -c /opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/stprm_dvr.c
make[6]: sh4gcc: Command not found
make[6]: *** [stprm_dvr.o] Error 127
make[6]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[5]: *** [default] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/stprm'
make[4]: *** [libstprm.a] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[3]: *** [default] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src'
make[2]: *** [/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/src/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS/libstdvm.a] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm/objs/b2067_h207_ST40_OS21_32BITS'
make[1]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/STM/STAPI_SDK/stapp/playrec/stdvm'
make: *** [stdvm] Error 2
```

Please help me I cannot find any package which contains sh4gcc cross-compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should specify that `sh4gcc` is a sh4 cross-compiler. Indeed, there doesn't seem to be such a compiler available for CentOS. What you can do is either install from source from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/tools/crosstool/files/bin/x86_64/4.6.3/) or use the Debian repo described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SH4/CrossToolchain) and `alien` to convert `deb`s to `rpm`s.